# JSONP with a dot in callback returning error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, jsonp

I am trying to make an ajax jsonp call.  Unfortunately the json that is returned has a dot in the callback function.  Please see below example:

```
ABCD.render_section({
"page": {
"parameters": {
  "pubDate": "2013-06-05 00:00:00.0",
  "PublishFile": "/indexes/2013/06/05/nyregion/index.html",
```

My ajax call that I'm attempting is

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    async: 'false', 
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonp : "callback",
    jsonpCallback: "ABCD",
    type : "GET",
    success(data){
            console.log(data);
    },
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log("Got an error...jqXHR=" + jqXHR.status + ", textStatus =" + textStatus + ", errorThrown=" + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

The error I am getting is Parseerror, ABCD is not defined.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `jsonpCallback` line in your `$.ajax` call and let jQuery create the called function and function name implicitly.